# Logging the data value when console logging

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys quick question my syntax is right and just want to  know is this the proper way to log the data value out of this table row.  When I click the glypicon I get the console log of "Edit" but the id is undefined. When I inspect the glypicon in the browser it has the correct data value.  I'm just trying to console log it when I click on it.

```
newrow.append($("<td><span onclick=editTask() i class='fas fa-edit glypiconSpace' data='" + taskid + "'></i></span><span onclick=deleteTask() i class='fas fa-trash-alt glypiconSpace2' data='" + taskid + "'></i></span></td>"))

function editTask() {
    console.log("edit")
    var id = ($(this).attr("data"));
    console.log(id)
}
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. I believe you are missing the open brace `<` for the `HTMLIconElement` and the closing brace for the preceding `span` tag.

Comment: If the previous comment is correct, the target of the event and the `this` keyword refers to the `span`, but the `data` attribute is on the `HTMLIconElement` and is not available via the `this' keyword (because `this` is the `<span>`;

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 mistakes:

1. You added `onclick` to `span` but `data` was added to `i`.
2. You used `this` in `editTask` but `this` makes no sense because there isn't any element for it. ([more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this))

You need to append and add listener in correct way like below:

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr id="newRow"></tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var taskid = "test";
var editSpan = $("<span> </span>");
var editIcon = $("<i class='fa fa-edit' data='" + taskid + "'></i>");

editIcon.click(function() {
  console.log("edit");
  var id = ($(this).attr("data"));
  console.log(id);
});

var yourTd = $("<td>");
$(yourTd).append(editSpan);
$(editSpan).append(editIcon);
$('#newRow').append(yourTd);
```

[**Online Demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/v4w2q6xL/30/)